# Why does nginx proxy send redirect message?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to pass the API requests to the backend with **NGINX reverse proxy**.

When I send a get request to */api/testdata*, it sends a request to {frontendURL}/api/testData which returns with 301(redirect) status code.
After that It redirects the request to the correct url {backendURL}/api/testData.

[image]

This is my config for it:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;



        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        server_name _;

        location /health {
                access_log off;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
                return 200 '{"status":"Healthy"}';
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001; 
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Can I somehow prevent the redirect request so that only one request goes out? Or is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: Nginx is not redirecting `/api/testdata` - the URL is passed to the application at `http://localhost:3001` and it is that application that generates the 301 status. Nginx simply passes the response back to the client.